# How to implement a comment section using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to implement a comments on each feed message using firebase database, but i'm not sure how to upload and then pull the comments. If my database looks something like what's attached how can I pull the data from firebase?

```
func uploadMessage(withContent content: String, withIcon icon: String, withColor color: String, withVotes votes: Int,sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()){
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["content" : content, "color" : color, "icon" : icon)
        sendComplete(true)
    }

func getFeedMessages(handler: @escaping (_ feedMessages:[FeedMessages]) -> ()){
        var feedMessagesArray = [FeedMessages]()
        REF_FEEDMESSAGES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (feedMessagesSnapshot) in
            guard let feedMessagesSnapshot = feedMessagesSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

            for messages in feedMessagesSnapshot {
                let content = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "content").value as? String ?? "Joe Flacco is an elite QB"
                let icon = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "icon").value as? String ?? "none"
                let color = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "color").value as? String ?? "bop"
                let votes = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "votes").value as? Int ?? 0
                let messages = FeedMessages(content: content, color: color, icon: icon, votes: votes)
                feedMessagesArray.append(messages)
            }
            handler(feedMessagesArray)
        }
    }
```

[image: image of firebase database]

Comment: Added print statement inside firebase callback ??

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: Before this line **handler(articleArray)** do **print(articleArray)**

Comment: when i check REF_ARTICLES in getAllArticles function it returns a link to my database in firebase

Comment: `let article = articleArray\[indexPath.row\]` what is this? should have been `let article = articleArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: it is correct in the code, not sure why it added those

Comment: What exactly is REF_ARTICLES?

Comment: its a reference to that child

Comment: He's asking how is it defined i.e. self.REF_ARTICLES = ????. Your crash ( NSNull' (0x1073ce850) to 'NSString' (0x105ff22a8)" error per below) may be caused by one of the nodes not containing one of the child nodes but you really need to do some troubleshooting to determine which line is crashing.

Comment: also, loose the handler and passing data around. All you should be doing is populating a class array variable, self.articleArray and then once you've looped through the article snapshots, just reload your tableView.

Comment: the issue could also be related to not having *articlesCell* defined in your UI properly.

Comment: im not sure what the underlying issue was but i just deleted the Article keys in firebase and remade them and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can firstly check the `REF_ARTICLES` value, then add a print in the first line of `observeSingleEvent` and check if `articleMessageSnapshot.children.allObjects` has value, I don't think so.

Maybe you don't do check for children, if you add an image of the firebase database tree we can help you.

Comment: theres a screenshot of the firebase database at the bottom of the post

Comment: when i check REF_ARTICLES in getAllArticles function it returns a link to my database in firebase

Comment: To the root of the database? Are you sure you are in the draftcalculator?

Comment: yes i had it working briefly, but now i'm getting a "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1073ce850) to 'NSString' (0x105ff22a8)" error